# cannot launch node of type [fcm_control/control_manager]: can't locate node [control_manager] in package [fcm_control]

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting above error when launching the launch file.
I am not able to debug this issue.I went through all the ros answers with similar problem.

I have sourced the setup.bash after catkin_make

this is my launch file

```
<launch>
    <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
    <rosparam file="$(find fcm_control)/src/JointSplineTrajectoryController.yaml" command="load" />
    <!-- <rosparam file="$(find fcm)/control/src/joint_trajectory_action.yaml" command="load" /> -->

    <!-- load the controller -->
    <node name="control_manager1" pkg="fcm_control" type="control_manager" respawn="false"
        output="screen" ns="fcm" args="linear_rail_controller" />

</launch>
```

This is the node file control_manager.cpp

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <fcm_hw/fcm.h>
#include <controller_manager/controller_manager.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    //setup
    ros::init(argc , argv , "my_robot");

    MyRobot::MyRobot robot;
    controller_manager::ControllerManager cm(&robot);

    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
    spinner.start();

    //control loop
    ros::Time prev_time = ros::Time::now();
    ros::Rate rate(10.0);

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        const ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
        const ros::Duration period = time - prev_time;

        robot.read();
        cm.update(time , period);
        robot.write();

        rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(fcm_control)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)


###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES fcm_control
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

my package directory

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── fcm_control
├── launch
│   ├── control.launch
│   └── display.launch
├── package.xml
└── src
    ├── control_manager.cpp
    ├── fcm.cpp
    ├── JointSplineTrajectoryController.yaml
    ├── joint_trajectory_action.yaml
    ├── readme.txt
    └── temp.py
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213779/cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bfcm_control/control_manager%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Bcontrol_manager%5D-in-package-%5Bfcm_control%5D/) by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-15**:
Can you also post the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if this is your complete `CMakeLists.txt`, the solution is simple.

You are not even building the node.
You need to specify in the `CMakeLists.txt` which source files you want to compile into which node. Add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
add_dependencies(control_manager src/control_manager.cpp)
target_link_libraries(control_manager ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

this will tell CMake to build a node called `control_manager` from the source file in `src/control_manager.cpp` and link the `catkin_LIBRARIES` against it.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1